# pythonでスクレイピング実行時でのエラーについて。

Tags: python, python3, web-scraping

下記にてpythonのスクレイピングを実行しているのですが、

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "link_network.py", line 81, in <module>
    G = make_network(args.url, urls)
  File "link_network.py", line 33, in make_network
    article_name= url.replace(entry_url,"").replace("/","-")
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'replace'
```

のエラーが表示されております。
どの部分にどう記載すればよいのかわからず、是非教えていただきたく存じます。

修正

```
def extract_url(root_url):
    page = 1
    is_articles = True
    urls = []

    while is_articles:
        UserAgent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_6) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/12.0 Safari/605.1.15'
        html = request.urlopen(request.Request(root_url, None, {'User-Agent': UserAgent}))
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
        articles = soup.find_all("a")
        for article in articles:
            href = article.get("href")
            if href:
                urls.append(href)
        is_articles = False
    return urls
```

Comment: 質問にお答えいただきありがとうございます。
スクレイピングのアクセスについて自分のサイト内でスクレイピングをしようとしてますので十分承知しております。ご指導ありがとうございます。

Comment: 重複候補: [Python3でwebスクレイピングしたいのですが存在するURLが開けません](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/27922)

Answer (score 1):

https://docs.python.org/ja/3.7/howto/urllib2.html#headers

このページを参考にするとヘッダーにuser agentが設定できると思います。

また、スクレイピングによって非常に高頻度のアクセスをかけるとサービスによってはipごとブロックをする場合があります。
その際に403が返ることも考えられますので最低でも１秒感覚のアクセスを心がけましょう。
こうなってしまっては同じipからはアクセスすることが不可能になるため気をつけたほうがいいです。
最悪の場合警察沙汰です。

https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%B2%A1%E5%B4%8E%E5%B8%82%E7%AB%8B%E4%B8%AD%E5%A4%AE%E5%9B%B3%E6%9B%B8%E9%A4%A8%E4%BA%8B%E4%BB%B6

Comment: コメントありがとうございます！勉強目的で自分の個人サイトにてテストをする予定ですので他サイトなどで迷惑をかけるような悪用はいたしません

Answer (score 1):

少なくとも UserAgent については、

```
request.urlopen(URL)
```

というような形式で open している部分を、URL 文字列ではなく、request.Request() オブジェクトを与えることで、指定できます。

```
UserAgent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_6) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/12.0 Safari/605.1.15'

request.urlopen(request.Request(URL, None, {'User-Agent': UserAgent}))
```

参考：[urllib.request --- URL を開くための拡張可能なライブラリ](https://docs.python.org/ja/3.8/library/urllib.request.html)

---

> NameError: name 'html' is not defined

については、`def make_network(root_url, urls):` の中の

```
try:
    UserAgent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_6) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/12.0 Safari/605.1.15'
    html = request.urlopen(request.Request(url, None, {'User-Agent': UserAgent}))
except urllib.error.HTTPError as e: 
    print(e.reason)
except urllib.error.URLError as e: 
    print(e.reason)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
```

が原因でしょう。html が try ブロックの内側のスコープにあるので、`BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")` の第1引数の html とは別物となり、未定義なのが原因です。

```
html = ''
try:
    UserAgent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_6) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/12.0 Safari/605.1.15'
    html = request.urlopen(request.Request(url, None, {'User-Agent': UserAgent}))
except urllib.error.HTTPError as e: 
    print(e.reason)
except urllib.error.URLError as e: 
    print(e.reason)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
```

としてみたらどうでしょうか？

Comment: ありがとうございます！もし可能ならレクチャーしていただけますでしょうか。
さきほど、
`while is_articles:
 UserAgent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_6) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/12.0 Safari/605.1.15'
 html = request.urlopen(request.Request(root_url, None, {'User-Agent': UserAgent}))`に変更したところ、再度エラーが起きてしまいました。

Comment: @steveeo では、質問文を更新して、改めて詳細なエラーログを示してみてください。UserAgent ではない別の原因だということになると思いますが。

Comment: @hata様
ありがとうございます！コードを修正したものを更新しましたのでご確認お願い致します。エラー表示も記載しております

Comment: @steveeo 回答を更新しました。

Comment: @hata様
ありがとうございます！htmlとは別物で未定義なのが原因だとは知りませんでした。プログラム素人で申し訳ございません。
指定されたコードに修正したところ、AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'replace'と表示されたのですがこちらどういうことなのでしょうか。。度々申し訳ございません
*コード修正しております

Comment: @steveeo `soup =` と `link =` の行のインデントが以前の状態と比べておかしくなっていますね。`try:` と同じインデントに戻してください。

Comment: @hata様　ご指摘ありがとうございます！インデント修正致しました！

Comment: @steveeo 実行時に -u オプションで url を指定して実行していますか？

Comment: @steveeo ladleさんの回答を反映してみてはどうでしょう。

Comment: レクチャーしていただき、本当にありがとうございました！無事にやりことができました!

Answer (score 1):

もしかしたら `placeholder hyperlink` が存在するのかもしれません。`placeholder hyperlink` というのは `href` 属性のない `a` 要素の事です。

[Elements/a - W3C Wiki](https://www.w3.org/wiki/Elements/a)

> If the href attribute is not specified, the element represents a placeholder hyperlink.

`placeholder hyperlink` が存在する場合、`extract_url` 関数の以下の部分で `urls` 変数(リスト)に `None` が含まれる事になります。

```
def extract_url(root_url):
           :    
    while is_articles:
           :    
        articles = soup.find_all("a")
        for article in articles:
            urls.append(article.get("href"))
           :    
    return urls
```

`article.get("href")` の戻り値が `None` の場合(`placeholder hyperlink`)は `urls` に含めない様に変更します。

```
        for article in articles:
            href = article.get("href")
            if href:
                urls.append(href)
```

これで試してみて下さい。

Comment: @ladle様
ありがとうございます！早速コードに反映させていただきました！
ターミナル上だと全くエラー表示されないのですが結果が表示されませんでした。
ターミナルで入力したものは、
`$ python link_network.py --url URL hogehoge -g`

Comment: `extract_url` 関数で、`is_articles = False` と `return urls` が抜け落ちてしまっています。

Comment: ありがとうございます！無事にやりたいことができました！