# BeautifulSoupでテーブルスクレイピング方法について

Tags: python, python3

Pythonで下記のURLをスクレイピングしたいです。

スクレイピングしたいテーブルのURL
[空港情報](https://www.narita-airport.jp/jp/flight/today?DepArr=D&flightDate=20220502&display=all&International=ON)

pandasを使うと簡単にテーブルをスクレイピングできる方法で行っています。

参考ページ
[BeautifulSoupでテーブルスクレイピング](https://qiita.com/go_honn/items/ec96c2246229e4ee2ea6)

ただ"urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden"のエラーが表示されので、
別のWEBページを読み込むコードを入れています。
その影響でpandasにて上手くスクレイピングできないです。

dfsにhtmlの変数を入れると”**ValueError**"が表示されます。
URLの代入方法は間違えていますでしょうか。

もし分かる方がいましたら、お手数ですが教えていただけると幸いです。

```
dfs = pd.read_html(html)
```

**エラー内容**

```
ValueError: No tables found
```

全体コード

```
import pandas as pd
import urllib.request

#url指定
url = 'https://www.narita-airport.jp/jp/flight/today?DepArr=D&flightDate=20220502&display=all&International=ON'

#参考:Python3でwebスクレイピングしたいのですが存在するURLが開けません。
#https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/27922/

headers = {
        "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:47.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/47.0",
        }

request = urllib.request.Request(url=url, headers=headers)
response = urllib.request.urlopen(request)
html = response.read().decode('utf-8')
print(html)


#参考：https://qiita.com/go_honn/items/ec96c2246229e4ee2ea6
#webページに複数のテーブルがある場合、リスト形式でdfsに格納されます
dfs = pd.read_html(html)
a=dfs[1] 

#Table print
print(a)
```

Comment: まずは結果を受け取った直後のデータにテーブルが含まれているかを確認するのが先かと思います。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。テーブルは含まれています。

Comment: ウェブブラウザの developer tools で通信状況を見てみると、`https://www.narita-airport.jp/jp/api/flight/?〜` へリダイレクトしています(`api` が追加されています)。

Comment: @metropolis さん
貴重な情報ありがとうございます。APIでテーブル情報をGetできるか。
確認致します。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

API を利用する場合。

```py
import pandas as pd
import urllib.request

url = 'https://www.narita-airport.jp/jp/api/flight/?DepArr=D&flightDate=20220502&flightDate=20220502&flightDate=20220502&display=all&International=ON'
headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:47.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/47.0',
    'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
}

request = urllib.request.Request(url=url, headers=headers)
response = urllib.request.urlopen(request)
html = response.read().decode('utf-8')

dfs = pd.read_html(html)
a = dfs[0].droplevel([0, 1, 3], axis=1).fillna('')

print(a[:10].to_markdown(index=False))
```

※ 先頭10行のみ表示

| 定刻 | 時刻変更 | 目的地 | 経由 | 便名・航空会社 | 便名・航空会社 | ターミナル | カウンター | ゲート | 機種情報 | 状況 | 所要時間 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 8:55 |  | ホーチミンシティ |  | VJ823 | ベトジェットエア | T2 | R | 96 | A21N | 出発済 | 6時間00分 |
| 9:00 |  | ソウル |  | OZ107 NH6977 | アシアナ航空○ ANA | T1-南 | H |  |  | 欠航 | 2時間30分 |
| 9:05 |  | 北京首都//ペキンシュト |  | NH957 | ANA | T1-南 | BC | 32 | B789 | 欠航 |  |
| 9:15 | [9:13] | 深圳//シェンツェン |  | NH931 | ANA | T1-南 | BC | 36 | B789 | 出発済 | 4時間50分 |
| 9:30 | [9:28] | マニラ |  | PR431 NH5335 | フィリピン航空○ ANA | T2 | Q | 93 | A321 | 出発済 | 5時間05分 |
| 9:30 | [9:27] | ハノイ |  | VJ933 | ベトジェットエア | T2 | R | 94 | A21N | 出発済 | 5時間35分 |
| 10:20 | [10:23] | クアラルンプール |  | MH71 FY7047 JL7093 | マレーシア航空○ ファイアーフライ 日本航空 | T2 | I | 73 | A333 | 出発済 | 7時間25分 |
| 10:30 |  | パリ |  | AF275 KL2295 | エールフランス○ KLM | T1-北 | C |  |  | 欠航 | 12時間40分 |
| 10:30 | [10:27] | メルボルン |  | JL8773 | 日本航空 | T2 | L M O P | 64 | B788 | 出発済 | 10時間25分 |
| 10:30 | [10:27] | カトマンズ |  | RA434 | ネパール航空 | T2 | Q | 95 | A332 | 出発済 |  |

Comment: @metropolisさん@nandeyanenさん
回答ありがとうございます。
質問ですが、droplevelの使い方を教えていただけますか。
例えばこちらのサイトもテーブル情報取得したいです。
https://www.naha-airport.co.jp/flight/today/

Comment: `IndexError: Too many levels: Index has only 1 level, not 2`のエラーが表示されます。
a = dfs[0].fillna('')にすると下記のように出力されますが、`Index: []`としてになります。この場合はどのように指定されますか。もし分かれば教えていただけると幸いです。
`Columns: [定刻[変更], 航空会社  航空会社便名, 便名, 目的地, ゲート, 備考]`
`Index: []`

Comment: まずスクレイピングのような法的にグレーなものは投稿は控えるか、投稿したとしても対象サイトがどこなのかわからないようにしたほうが良いのではないかと思うんですが、どうなんでしょうか。あとpandasの一般的な使い方がわからないというレベルの話なら別の質問として立ち上げたほうが良いと思いますよ。@metropolis @sakaolo

Comment: @sakaolo 那覇空港の場合は `https://www.naha-airport.co.jp/fis/fis_national.json` からデータを取り出しています。response は JSON テキストで過去3日程度のデータが入っていて加工する必要があるので、この場合は Selenium を使う方が簡単でしょう。

Comment: @nandeyanen さん、私は法律の専門家ではありませんが私がよく目にしている意見として、(1) 一般に向けて公開されているサイトの URL を投稿する行為はふつう問題にならないです。(2) 機械的なデータに著作性を見出すのは難しいです。(3) スクレイピングは規約などで明示的に禁止されている場合を除いて、一般常識の範疇で行うのであれば特に違法な行為ではありません。たとえば Google のクローラーは毎日スクレイピングを続けています。岡崎市立中央図書館事件のようにサーバーに過度な負荷を与えると問題になることはありますが、今回のデータ取得は 1 回きりです。

Comment: まあその辺りは自己責任かと思いますが、初心者だとしたら気をつけるに越したことはないと思います (一回きりなのは投稿から見える範囲でしかないので)。なので私もその辺りを気にして回答を削除しましたが、私は気をつけるという話なので、他の方がご自身でどう行動されるかはまあやっぱ自己責任かと。

Comment: @metropolis さん
回答ありがとうございます。Seleniumか別の方法でもやってみます。
@nandeyanenさん、＠nekketsuuuさん
スクレイピングの違法な行為について教えてくれてありがとうございます。
これから期間の範囲についてやそのページ禁止されているか。
確認してから行います。今回はこの方法は勉強のために行っております。

Comment: @metropolis さん
度々、すいません。API情報についての質問です。
昨日フライト情報も取得したい場合、APIありますでしょうか。
下記のURLに昨日の日付変更してみましたが、取得出来ませんでした。
もし分かりましたら、教えていただけると幸いです。
 `https://www.narita-airport.jp/jp/api/flight/?DepArr=D&flightDate=20220509&flightDate=20220509&flightDate=20220509&display=all&International=ON `

Comment: すいません、大丈夫です。下記のURLでいけました。
`https://www.narita-airport.jp/jp/api/flight/?DepArr=A&flightDate=20220509&International=ON&display=all`